# Polygons are being drawn when I modify an unrelated, undrawn array

Tags: c, opengl

I am implementing Catmull-Clark subdivision on a mesh using OpenGL. I can draw my mesh just fine, and I do so using a vertex array.

The array that I draw is called extraVert1[].

In order to implement this subdivision, I have to do operations on certain points besides just the vertices used to draw. I have implemented the standard half-edge data structure in order to iterate through the edges of the mesh and generate the edge-points needed to subdivide.

**The issue is here**

When I calculate edge-points, I store them into a vertex array, and make the corresponding face point to this edge-point vertex (of which each face points to 4).

The code snippet is as follows (edgeAry1[] is the array of half-edges)

```
    edgePoint1[j].x = (edgeAry1[i].end->x + edgeAry1[i].next->next->next->end->x + edgeAry1[i].heFace->center.x + edgeAry1[i].opp->heFace->center.x) / 4.0;
    edgePoint1[j].y = (edgeAry1[i].end->y + edgeAry1[i].next->next->next->end->y + edgeAry1[i].heFace->center.y + edgeAry1[i].opp->heFace->center.y) / 4.0;
    edgePoint1[j].z = (edgeAry1[i].end->z + edgeAry1[i].next->next->next->end->z + edgeAry1[i].heFace->center.z + edgeAry1[i].opp->heFace->center.z) / 4.0;

    faceAry1[i].e = &edgePoint1[j];
    j++;
```

When this code executes (it loops through for each face in faceAry1[]), I get random edges and triangles around the center of my mesh, even though I never make any changes to extraVert1[], the array I draw from.

I thought this had something to do with my pointers, so I individually commented out each operand and none of them changed anything. I then set every line equal to just 4.0. This gave me a single extra triangle, with points [approximately] (0,0,0), (4,0,0), (4,4,4).

When debugging, I went through the extraVer1[] array both before and after this section of code. It remained unchanged. My draw code is: (extraVert has size 408)

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

 glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, extraVert1);

 glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 408);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Again, I'm not modifying the drawing array extraVert1[] in any way, so I'm completely stumped as to why this is occurring. I'm sure I'll need to provide more information if anyone is interested in answering, so feel free to ask for it. I'm going to keep working at it for now until then.

*UPDATE*

It seems that using a different array large enough to store these values (in this case, extraVert2[]). The problem seems to be one of overwriting memory, but I'm not sure exactly how. When my arrays are declared like so:

```
face faceAry1[34];
float extraVert1[408];
halfEdge edgeAry1[136];
vertex edgePoint1[136];
vertex extraVert2[1632];
```

I can store the information in extraVert2[] with no issues. If I flip the order of extraVert2[] and edgePoint1[], I get the same issue as before. Anyone know what causes this?

Comment: would print out values in each loop helps?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know how 3D-rendering works, *random* edges and triangles usually occurs from [uninitialized variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable) or [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). These two are usually the cause of unexpected *random* behaviour in my programs. I too think this has something to do with your pointers, but as I have no knowledge of 3D-rendering it could be related to any 3D-specific context aswell.

Comment: Iterating through extraVert1[], both before at after these calls, shows that this array has every value initialized and set properly. Nothing is modifying this array, and even when I remove everything dealing with pointers (something like edgePointer1[i] = 4.0; etc) I still get a similar issue. It could be something funky with OpenGL so I'll try renaming things and fiddling a bit more.

Also, changing edgePoint1[] to an array of floats (and tripling its size) still created the same issue.